# Javascript set select box size attribute does not seem to work

Tags: javascript

I have a select box with the class attribute set to `class="styled"`. The reason being that the select box has been styled (it uses a background url to give it a custom appearance). If I remove this class attribute I can simple use `size="10"` in the html tag, or change it dynamically with:

```
var o_select = document.getElementById("mySelect");

o_select.size = "10";
```

(or, `o_select.setAttribute("size", "10");`)

It seems to be the class attribute causing the problems. Please help!

Comment: you need to show some HTML so that we can tell what we're dealing with.

Comment: also, welcome to the community; please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and learn to use markdown.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine

```
<select class="styled" id="mySelect">
    <option>This is an option</option>
    <option>This is another option</option>
</select>
```

and

```
var o_select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
o_select.size = "10";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/LSP8p/1/

What other HTML / JS have you got happening?